# prefsdialogimpl.cpp:61:18: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

Tags: c++, kde-plasma

Debian Testing with kernel 3.16-2-amd64 and KDE 4.14.1. Not cross-compiling. Using cmake.

Trying to resuscitate an old KDE app but:

```
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/knet.dir/prefsdialogimpl.o
/usr/local/src/knet/prefsdialogimpl.cpp: In member function ‘void PrefsDialogImpl::setDeviceChoices(QVector<QString>)’:
/usr/local/src/knet/prefsdialogimpl.cpp:61:18: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
for( uint i=0; i<choices.count(); i++ )
```

The relevant function looks like this:

```
void PrefsDialogImpl::setDeviceChoices( QVector< QString > choices )
{
    for( uint i=0; i<choices.count(); i++ )
        diagram_deviceComboBox->insertItem((choices[i]), i );
}
```

And the entire file, prefsdialogimpl.cpp, is here:  https://pastee.org/fhb3u

I am not finding where the unsigned integer is, and do not know how to fix it.  I am new with c++ but am learning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have neglected to ask a question. Please [edit] your question to include a complete sentence telling what problem you're facing. You've provided a compiler error; what prevents you from fixing it?

Comment: The warning clearly tells you where it has a problem. I would guess that `choices.count` returns a (signed) integer value, which you compare with `uint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up [the documentation for QVector::count()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvector.html#count-2), you can see that `count` returns a signed integer value. When this value is compared to your `i`, which is an `uint`, a sign mismatch occurs.

You can fix this discrepancy by changing the definition of `i` to be `int i`.

Comment: Very nice, thank you Magnus.  I don't understand though that this same statement is used in three functions around this one, yet they don't fail.  I set them to integers, and then they get the signed/unsigned error.

Comment: @Bill Of course it is not the same. What is the difference between this function and the others? `choices` has a different type. How can this have an effect? Because, of course, the `count` function is different. Go and look up the documentation for the other `count` function and find the cause of the discrepancy. Looking up documentation should be second nature, especially when you are learning, and I think you have gotten some downvotes merely because you have not looked up the documentation. Take this as a training exercise ;) :)